# How to 'tab' an entire paragraph while composing an email in Thunderbird Mail?

Tags: thunderbird

How to 'tab' an entire paragraph while composing an email in Thunderbird Mail? By referring 'tab', I mean to say a margin of white spaces to be provided to a paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Thunderbird, select Write and type your paragraph.

On completion, highlight the whole paragraph you want indented and then select the option Indent Text (move right).

Your whole paragraph will then be indented.

[image]